# Which coding style is more readable or preferable?

Tags: coding-style, standards

In the below 2 ways, which method one has to prefer. I personally comfortable with method 2, the `if-else`ladder one. But my friend told, they invoke redundancy in coding., and he used to achieve that in many single `if` statements, like..
Examples:

```
    if( cond1 && cond2 ){}
    if(cond1 && cond3){}
    if(cond3 && cond2){} etc..

Instead of.,

    if(cond1)
    {
    }
    else
    {
    if(cond3 && cond2)
    {}
    }

//Way 1
    String str = cond1 && !cond2 && !cond3 ? "world" : "hello" ;

(cond1,cond2,cond3 -> aren't simple checks. say they itself contains many || and &&'s )

//Way 2
            String str;
            if (cond1)
            {
                if (cond2)
                {
                    str = "hello";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (cond3)
                    {
                        str = "hello";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        str = "world";
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Use whatever fits best your needs and what you can read better.

Comment: Depends on the reader...As Shakespeare said, "Beauty lies in the eyes of beholder."

Comment: There's a bit of an in-between method here.  Personally, I like neither.

Answer (score 2):

```
String str;
if (cond1 && cond2) {
    str = "hello";
} else if(cond1 && cond3) {
    str = "hello";
} else if(cond1) {
    str = "world";
}
```

This method is a bit inbetween the two.  I am not a fan of the first method at all.  But personally, this method seems a bit more clear than your second method and more readable, and it does the same thing.

This isn't to suggest that you should avoid nesting `if` statements.  I'm merely suggesting that you should feel free to use compound `if` statements also.  In my opinion, the contents of an `if else` block should be more than just more nested `if` or `if else`.  If there is nothing inside your `if` block that's not in a `nested if` block, then your statement can be rewritten with compound `if statements`.

There's an alternate to my first method also.

```
String str;
if(cond1) {
    if(cond2) {
        //do stuff
    } else if(cond3) {
        //do stuff
    } else {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

This will check `cond1` just once.  It still has a purely nested `if` that can be rewritten as `compound`, but if you're concerned about performance (if `cond1` is a particularly time-consuming check), this will check `cond1` just once, and it still more readable than what you offered in the question originally (in my opinion).  This difference is more subtle.

There's also this method.

```
bool flag1 = cond1;
bool flag2 = cond2;
bool flag3 = cond3;

String str;
if (flag1 && flag2) {
    str = "hello";
} else if(flag1 && flag3) {
    str = "hello";
} else if(flag1) {
    str = "world";
}
```

In this method, you can make simple and short compound condition statements by using `bool` variables as flags.  You can check any of the conditions as many times as you want (any time the condition may change, you need to `flag1 = cond1` again, etc), without doing all the computing it may take to actually check the condition.  You just check it once and save the result of the condition.

Comment: I feel a redundancy in checking cond1 -> 3 times., which I feel it may reduce the performance.

Comment: There is some redundancy.  You can rewrite this a few different ways.  And it depends on the language.  For instance, Java will short-circuit `&&`, so you can rewrite `if(cond1 && cond2)` to `if(cond2 && cond1)` and it will only check `cond1` if `cond2` returned true.  It depends on how complex each condition your checking is in terms of performance.  But a tiny tiny hit to performance for a massive readability improvement is fine in most cases.

Comment: And it is `cond1 && cond3` in the first else if.

Comment: Fixed that, and added yet another alternative method that addresses some of your performance concerns.

Comment: your alternate method is very same as my preferred method. But if will not like the floating `else if`., without ending `else` because I feel the code to be incomplete without endling else. So, I will generally include `{}` for the `else {if()}` instead of `else if()` :P

Comment: You can't consider my second method to be the very same unless you consider my first method and your first method and my third method all to also be the very same.  They all do the same thing.  You can always add `else { /*do nothing*/ }` for "completeness" if you want.  But an `else if` without an ending `else` is no more "incomplete" than an `if` without an ending `else`.  Anyway, I added a third method too.

Comment: I generraly do this `else ; //do nothing` And I thought it is not a standard.

Comment: Hmm, I misunderstood what you are saying at first.  From a purely readability standpoint, I personally consider the `if(){} else if(){} else{}` style to be far more readable.  From a logic standpoint, you only want to do one set of instructions, and they're all from the same subset.  When you do `else{if(){}}` it looks more like a subset of the subset... if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many different types of coding styles and from all that I have found, it all depends on the situation. There is not a universal standard, other than do not write un-readable code.

Your colleagues may desire a specific stylistic pattern and thus you follow that one.

To a moderately experienced programmer both are very readable and readability is very important for code, especially if it is going to be maintained by somebody else(which is eventually inevitable).

It is all what your goals are. If you want large `if/else` statements, I am not sure there is an inherent reason not too, other than it may eventually make unreadable code, depending on how it is implemented.